# How to use BETWEEN in postgres jsonb?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have some jsonb data like:

```
{  
   "id":"58fd893414a570155ddf5120",
   "TPDId":"10101",
   "Services":[  
      "10093"
   ],
   "DaysInstances":[  
      17304,
      17300,
      17301,
      17302,
      17303
   ],
   "TPDProperties":{  
      "DisplayLabel":"TP display label W0ichP6h",
      "TimePeriodType":"Maintenance"
   }
}
```

The field **DaysInstances** is an array.

Now I want select records which **DaysInstances** has value between 17300 and 17303.

I tried this kind of sql but no use:

```
SELECT body FROM "TimePeriodInstance_100000001" where (body -> 'DaysInstances') between '17300' AND '17303';
```

This sql is worked but too difficult to splice in our system now :

```
SELECT DISTINCT body FROM "TimePeriodInstance_100000001" cross join 
json_array_elements((body -> 'DaysInstances')::json) where value::text::int between '17300' AND '17303';
```

Any other ideas?  Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without aggregation & `LATERAL`, with a plain old correlating subquery (with `EXISTS`):

```
SELECT body
FROM   "TimePeriodInstance_100000001"
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   jsonb_array_elements(body -> 'DaysInstances') e
              WHERE  e BETWEEN '17300' AND '17303')
```

*Note*: the `BETWEEN` constraints are actually (implicitly) typed `jsonb`, which has comparison operators to back it up. If you want to bind `int`s f.ex., you will need casts to make it work (or use something like `BETWEEN to_jsonb($1) AND to_jsonb($2)`).

http://rextester.com/GAA60634

Comment: It's works! Thank you very much!  The EXISTS has any performance problem in query?

Comment: @LouieLiu The `EXISTS` is the most performant in these situations anyway. But because you are unwinding an array, no index can be used. -- If you would query for equality, the containment operators (`<@` or `@>`) could be used with `jsonb` indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

(Works, if jsons `id` field is unique for every row)

```
select test1.* from test1 inner join (
    select json_id from (
        select col->>'id' as json_id, jsonb_array_elements_text(col->'DaysInstances') as arrel from test1
    )t where arrel::numeric between 17300 and 17303
    GROUP BY json_id
) t2
on test1.col->>'id' = t2.json_id
```

If you have unique identity column (say `id`), then better use this:

```
select test1.* from test1 inner join (
    select id from (
        select id, jsonb_array_elements_text(col->'DaysInstances') as arrel from test1
    )t where arrel::numeric between 17300 and 17303
    GROUP BY id
) t2
on test1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Yes, it's works! But we can't use join in this query, thanks anyway!!